# Can I stream with Airplay from my iPhone to a compatible 3rd Party device?

Tags: iphone, streaming, airplay, 3rd-party

It may be just me, but Apple's website seems to beat around the bush regarding the use of Airplay. I just need to know: Over wireless can I stream directly from my iPhone to an Airplay-Enabled 3rd party sound system (No AppleTV, no Airport Express, no Macbook)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Apple licenses the receiver portion of AirPlay to 3rd party manufacturers, so they can build compatible receivers meant to work with iOS and OS X devices.

As long as the device you're going to use is AirPlay compatible, it should work.